# Most cost-effective way to stream video in a website

Tags: web, streaming, video-streaming, p2p, rtmp

**Problem.**

I would like to create a website and play a video stream on it, but I'm not well-familiar with such kind of technologies. I've been researching for several days trying to find the most cost-effective solution. Unfortunately, I didn't come up with it yet.

There are several important moments:

- I would like to support both desktop and mobile devices (i.e., switch between Flash and HTML5).
- Video stream is captured from the screen of my PC.
- I would like to provide an ability to switch between LQ and HQ.

**Notes:**

- My bandwidth ain't good enough to stream over all users (approximately up to 2000 per day).
- I wonder if there a way to organize a p2p streaming. It would probably solve my bandwidth problem.
- If there is no way to stream directly from my PC, I don't know whether I should rent an appropriate server and run a certain software on it or find a service which will consume my video stream and stream it to users.
- Ustream.tv is completely ok. But it's pretty expensive as well (have to buy premium to stream in HD).
- Justin.tv is not supporting mobile devices (have to download app as far as I know).
- My current solution is Wowza Media Server + Adobe Live encoder + JW Player. But it's (Wowza Media Server) is running on my PC because I'm not familiar with renting servers.
- My budget is around 300-400$ per month.

Any solutions/suggestions are appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont have good bandwidth, streaming from your pc or hosting streaming servers from your end is out of question. Like you mentioned, there are lots of 3rd party offering you streaming solutions, but they expensive... but there are a few cheap service providers as well. You can look at them...

Another great free option will be the newly launched Youtube Live. You will have to enable "Live" streaming feature in your account. Looks like you will have to be eligible to have it enabled.

http://www.youtube.com/live/all

If its enables, you can push your pre-recorded video files/live video to the google's publishing point. For that you can use any supported media encoders. More info can be read here on how to set it up.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en&ref_topic=2853713

Once thats setup, you can stream events as if its a real live event !

Few paid thirdparty streaming below (Google for more ofcource)

http://www.dacast.com/streaming-pricing-plans.html

http://www.primcast.com/services?gclid=CJKJ7_CCwrwCFc9U4godoRAABw

http://livestreamingcdn.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will read more about Youtube Live. You said that there are a few cheap service providers. Can you please list them? My budget is around 300-400$ per month.

Comment: @ErnestTen, I've updated my answer to include couple of links.

Answer (score 0):

"My current solution is Wowza Media Server + Adobe Live encoder + JW Player. But it's (Wowza Media Server) is running on my PC because I'm not familiar with renting servers."

The same solution but on powerful servers is offered by http://www.serverroom.net/wowza-dedicated for up to 2000 viewers connected in the same time the budget of $300-$400 is more then enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC or ffmpeg to capture your screen and use f.e. this [videopeer.io](https://videopeer.io/) platform to transform your stream to MPEG-DASH and their p2p plaer.